# How to grep lines that have the pattern between start and end position in the line?

Tags: shell

I have the below sample of file:

```
123456789000000000123456789000000000

123456789123456789123456789000000000
```

I want to grep for the lines that have `000000000` between 10th and 18th position of the line. In such a way that second line will be skipped/ignored.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You must use `^` for the start of line and `.` for any character.
You can start with

```
echo "123456789000000000123456789000000000
123456789123456789123456789000000000" | grep "^.........000000000"
```

For this command you need to count the characters in the command.
The command can be simplified to

```
echo "123456789000000000123456789000000000
123456789123456789123456789000000000" | grep -E "^.{9}0{9}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do with `awk` using `substr` without using any regex:

```
awk 'substr($0, 10, 9) != "000000000"' file

123456789123456789123456789000000000
```

`substr($0, 10, 9)` will get substring of each record between 10th position and 18th position.

You can also use:

```
awk 'substr($0, 10, 9) != sprintf("%09d", 0)' file
```

`sprintf("%09d", 0)` will print `0` 9 times.